# использовать функции из linux .so

Tags: c++, linux, library

Линкую .so библиотеку динамически. Не могу найти, как использовать функции .cpp-файлов из которых собрана эта библиотека.

Comment: Почему не можете найти, или как вы искали?

Comment: только сишное все... я думал есть в стандартной библиотеке что-то для этого... ни разу не сталкивался

Comment: "есть в стандартной библиотеке что-то для этого" - для чего для этого?

Comment: для импорта/экспорта функций из so-шки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

примерно так:

```
void* handle = dlopen(path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
if (!handle)
     const char* err = dlerror();

pfunc func = (pfunc)dlsym(handle, "func"); 
func()

dlclose(handle);
```

Comment: хм, думал для c++ есть что-то другое

Comment: Ну обертки для этого есть, POCO например

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, пожалуй заюзаю boost.dll